# ScrollBar Vb6 Query

Tags: forms, vb6, scrollbar

I have an application in `VB6` in which after pressing the add button fields are added within a `UserControl`.

[image]

What I need is to manage those `UserControl` with a `ScrollBar` so that the **User** can go down the bar without the need to enlarge the form.

[image]

Currently this is the whole code:

```
Dim indice As Integer
Dim indicee As Integer

Private Sub btnAñadir_Click()
indice = indice + 1 'aumentamos el index
indicee = indicee + 0 'lo iniciamos en 0
uc1(indicee).Visible = True

'Label y TextBox de tipo
lblTipo(indicee).Visible = True
cmbAddTipo(indicee).Visible = True

'Label y TextBox de prefijo
lblAddPrefijo(indicee).Visible = True
txtAddPrefijo(indicee).Visible = True

'Label y TextBox de número
lblAddNum(indicee).Visible = True
txtAddNumero(indicee).Visible = True

chkAddPrincipal(indicee).Visible = True

'Label y TextBox de vínculo
lblAddVin(indicee).Visible = True
cmbAddVinculo(indicee).Visible = True

'uc1
Load uc1(indice) ' creamos el control
uc1(indice).Visible = True ' lo hacemos visible
uc1(indice).Top = uc1(indice - 1).Top + uc1(indice - 1).Height + 20

'lblTipo
Load lblTipo(indice)
Set lblTipo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
lblTipo(indice).Visible = True
lblTipo(indice).Top = lblTipo(indice - 1).Top
'cmbAddTipo
Load cmbAddTipo(indice)
Set cmbAddTipo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
cmbAddTipo(indice).Visible = True
cmbAddTipo(indice).Top = cmbAddTipo(indice - 1).Top

'lblAddPrefijo
Load lblAddPrefijo(indice)
Set lblAddPrefijo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
lblAddPrefijo(indice).Visible = True
lblAddPrefijo(indice).Top = lblAddPrefijo(indice - 1).Top
'txtAddPrefijo
Load txtAddPrefijo(indice)
Set txtAddPrefijo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
txtAddPrefijo(indice).Visible = True
txtAddPrefijo(indice).Top = txtAddPrefijo(indice - 1).Top

'lblAddNum
Load lblAddNum(indice)
Set lblAddNum(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
lblAddNum(indice).Visible = True
lblAddNum(indice).Top = lblAddNum(indice - 1).Top
'txtAddNumero
Load txtAddNumero(indice)
Set txtAddNumero(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
txtAddNumero(indice).Visible = True
txtAddNumero(indice).Top = txtAddNumero(indice - 1).Top

'checkAddPrincipal
Load chkAddPrincipal(indice)
Set chkAddPrincipal(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
chkAddPrincipal(indice).Visible = True
chkAddPrincipal(indice).Top = chkAddPrincipal(indice - 1).Top

'lblAddVin
Load lblAddVin(indice)
Set lblAddVin(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
lblAddVin(indice).Visible = True
lblAddVin(indice).Top = lblAddVin(indice - 1).Top
'cmbAddVinculo
Load cmbAddVinculo(indice)
Set cmbAddVinculo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
cmbAddVinculo(indice).Visible = True
cmbAddVinculo(indice).Top = cmbAddVinculo(indice - 1).Top

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
'scrollAdd
scrollAdd.Min = 0
scrollAdd.Max = 1000
scrollAdd.SmallChange = Screen.TwipsPerPixelX * 10
scrollAdd.LargeChange = scrollAdd.SmallChange

End Sub

Private Sub scrollAdd_Change()
UserControl1
End Sub


Private Sub scrollAdd_Scroll()
UserControl1
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl1()
   Dim c As Control

   For Each c In Me.Controls
      If c.Container.Name = "uc1" And Not TypeOf c Is scrollAdd Then
         c.Down = c.Down - (oldPos - scrollAdd.Value)
      End If
   Next

   oldPos = scrollAdd.Value
End Sub
```

How do I do that after having added several fields with the add button I can go using the `ScrollBar` to download the form?
And when i press the `ScrollBar I get the message: Sub or Function is not defined vb6` and this error is in line: `Private Sub UserControl1()`

Comment: [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44181917/5162073) to a similar question.  The code in this link scrolls left to right, but it shouldn't be too hard to modify it to scroll up and down.

Comment: Yeah, but not work to me. Y edited my post with the new code added. @BrianMStafford

Comment: You need to change `c.Down` to `c.Top` and add the change.  Like this `c.Top = c.Top + (oldPos - scrollAdd.Value)`

Comment: Thank You for the answer @BrianMStafford

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Private Sub Command1_Click()
     Load txtCode(txtCode.UBound + 1)
     txtCode(txtCode.UBound).Top = txtCode(txtCode.UBound - 1).Top + 
     txtCode(txtCode.UBound - 1).Height
     txtCode(txtCode.UBound).Text = txtCode.UBound
     txtCode(txtCode.UBound).Visible = True
     Picture2.Height = (txtCode(txtCode.UBound).Top + 
     txtCode(txtCode.UBound).Height) + 150
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form_Load()
    Picture2.Top = Picture1.Top
    Picture2.Left = Picture1.Left

    Picture2.Height = Picture1.Height
    Picture2.Width = Picture2.Width
  End Sub

  Private Sub Picture2_Resize()
     If Picture2.Height > Picture1.Height Then
         If Not HScroll1.Visible Then
            HScroll1.Visible = True
            VScroll1.Visible = True
         End If
         VScroll1.Max = (Picture2.Height - Picture1.Height) / 
         txtCode(txtCode.UBound).Height
         VScroll1.Min = 0
         VScroll1.Value = 0
     Else
     If HScroll1.Visible Then
        HScroll1.Visible = False
        VScroll1.Visible = False
     End If
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub VScroll1_Change()
     Picture2.Top = -(VScroll1.Value * txtCode(txtCode.UBound).Height)
  End Sub
```

You may refer for more in the link below:

[ http://www.esjay.org/2019/12/13/scrollbar-using-vb6/ ]