# Check with adding / removing objects in VB6

Tags: button, combobox, vb6, controls

I have a query, I have this interface:

[image]

The ComboBox are inside a UserControl, pressing the Add this UserControl button with the ComboBox adds the UserControl / ComboBox in a PictureBox:

[image]

What I want is that, for example, when the user selects values ​​of the two ComboBox and press the button add these selected values ​​go to the PictureBox (below) and the values ​​that are selected in the UserControl are cleaned.I leave a picture of what I say, suppose the user selected the values ​​of the combos:

[image]

Once you have selected them, the add these button is enabled, they pass below and those above are cleaned:

[image]

But, if I press the remove button you must remove the last loaded object and move to the top. I leave a descriptive image, press the remove button:

[image]

The bottom disappears and goes up:

[image]

Currently this is the code I use to add:

```
Option Explicit
Dim indice As Integer

Public Property Let AddType(ByVal Value As String)
   cmbAddExample.Text = Value
End Property

Private Sub btnAñadir_Click()
   indice = indice + 1

   Picture1.Visible = True

   Load uc1(indice)
   Set uc1(indice).Container = Picture1
   uc1(indice).Visible = True
   uc1(indice).Top = IIf(indice = 1, 0, uc1(indice - 1).Top + uc1(indice - 1).Height + 20)

   Load cmbAddExample(indice)
   Set cmbAddExample(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   cmbAddExample(indice).Visible = True
   cmbAddExample(indice).Top = cmbAddExample(indice - 1).Top
   CargaIDTipoNumero

   uc1(indice).AddType = uc1(0).AddType
   uc1(indice).AddType = ""


   If indice = 3 Then
   Me.btnAñadir.Enabled = False
   End If
End Sub
```

So, does anyone have any idea how I can do what I am looking for? Or yes, is it possible?

Button Remove:

```
Private Sub btnQuitar_Click()
   indice = cmbAddExample().Count - 1
   If indice > 0 Then
       Unload cmbAddExample(indice)
       End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible.  Do you have any code where you've tried doing this?

Comment: Yes, I added the code where i'm trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59410212/5162073) as the starting point, you can implement these requirements fairly easily.  I have copied relevant code from the other answer and modified it:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
   index = index + 1

   Load uc1(index)
   Set uc1(index).Container = Picture1
   uc1(index).Visible = True
   uc1(index).Top = IIf(index = 1, 0, uc1(index - 1).Top + uc1(index - 1).Height + 20)

   'copy the information down
   uc1(index).AddType = uc1(0).AddType
   uc1(0).AddType = ""

   Picture1.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub btnRemove_Click()
   If index = 0 Then Exit Sub

   'copy the information back up and remove the control
   uc1(0).AddType = uc1(index).AddType
   Unload uc1(index)

   index = index - 1
   If index = 0 Then Picture1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

I have only coded for one control to illustrate the concept.  You can add other controls as needed.

Comment: i've a dude, AddType is a property to get/let TextBox but in this case where you use uc1, how i do to modify this property to uc1?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.  However, in your sample code above it looks like you are adding the 2 combos programmatically.  If this is true, then you have no way of accessing the underlying combo.  Those controls need to be added at design time along with the associated properties.  Refer to my linked answer for more details.

Comment: AddType is a get / let property that you wrote in your response. That property is based on a ComboBox. But, in this case you put AddType in the UserControl. So, my question is how did you modify that AddType property to be UserControl?

Comment: In my linked answer, AddType is a property of the UserControl.  The ComboBox is a control on the UserControl.  Both of which were created at design-time, not run-time.  With this architecture, the solution to your problem is simple.  Without it, the solution becomes much harder.  Again, I would suggest carefully going through my linked answer.  This answer is dependent upon the linked answer's design.

Comment: In my case, when i press the button to add, the application shows me the next error: compile error not found the method or data member. This error is in line `AddType`  in uc1(0).AddType. I edited my code in the question, i added the property and your example

Comment: Exactly.  Please refer to my last 2 comments.

Comment: Don't add the `AddType` property to the form.  Add it to the UserControl like I do in the linked answer.

Comment: What you mean is that in my project I right click, press add and add a USerControl. So, within that UserControl should I add the properties?

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Yes, add the properties within the UserControl.

Comment: I created the UserControl, I added the properties within it but at the time of running the application it shows me the following error: 'User Defined Type Not Defined'
Sorry, i wrote in spanish 'cause is my native language

Comment: So, i've a solution. I'll add captures and the UserControl code with the properties and with the error you understand it in a new question

Comment: Again, I provided a working example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59410212/5162073) which shows how to do this.

Comment: Yes, and i implemented your example in my project with the objects that i need but, how to say previously when i run app, it shows me the following error: 'User Defined Type Not Defined