# Load and save values in VB6

Tags: sql-server, combobox, textbox, vb6

So, this is my interface:

[image]

This is my UserControl:

[image]

TextBox = Text1 / ComboBox = cmbAddExample

This is the code from `UserControl`:

```
Option Explicit
Dim cnn As Connection
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim sql As Command

Private Sub UserControl_Initialize()
   Set rs = New Recordset
   rs.CursorLocation = adUseServer
   Call IniciarConexion
   CargaIDTipoNumero
End Sub

Public Property Get AddType() As String
   AddType = cmbAddExample.Text
End Property

Public Property Let AddType(ByVal Value As String)
   cmbAddExample.Text = Value
End Property

Public Property Get AddNumber() As String
   AddNumber = Text1.Text
End Property

Public Property Let AddNumber(ByVal Value As String)
   Text1.Text = Value
End Property

Private Sub CargaIDTipoNumero()
cmbAddExample.Clear
rs.Open "SELECT idTipo, tipo FROM tipo_Numero", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
Do While rs.EOF = False
    cmbAddExample.AddItem rs!tipo
    cmbAddExample.ItemData(cmbAddExample.NewIndex) = rs!idTipo
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
End Sub

Private Sub IniciarConexion()
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    With cnn
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open "PROVIDER=MSDASQL;driver={SQL Server};server=server;uid=uid;pwd=pwd;database=database;"
    End With
End Sub
```

In my form, I have these methods to connect and load data from SQLServer:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   Set rs = New Recordset
   rs.CursorLocation = adUseServer
   Picture1.Visible = False
   Call IniciarConexion
   CargaIDTipoNumero
End Sub

Private Sub IniciarConexion()
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    With cnn
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open "PROVIDER=MSDASQL;driver={SQL Server};server=server;uid=uid;pwd=pwd;database=database;"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CargaIDTipoNumero()
cmbAddExample(indice).Clear
rs.Open "SELECT idTipo, tipo FROM tipo_Numero", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
Do While rs.EOF = False
    cmbAddExample(indice).AddItem rs!tipo
    cmbAddExample(indice).ItemData(cmbAddExample(indice).NewIndex) = rs!idTipo
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
End Sub
```

So, the problem is as follows:

[image]

```
compilation error sub or function not defined
```

in line: `cmbAddExample(indice).Clear`

Finally, I have a "Guardar" `button` that saves the data in SQLServer:

```
Private Sub btnGuardar_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim id As Integer

Dim CM As ADODB.Command

For i = 0 To indice
id = cmbAddExample(i).ItemData(cmbAddExample(i).ListIndex)

Set CM = New ADODB.Command
Set CM.ActiveConnection = cnn
    CM.CommandType = adCmdText
    CM.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ejemplo (combo,nombre) VALUES (?,?)"
    CM.Parameters.Append CM.CreateParameter("@txt", adInteger, , , id)
    CM.Parameters.Append CM.CreateParameter("@comboDos", adInteger, , , Text1(i).Text)
    CM.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
Next
End Sub
```

How do I load the ComboBox with the SQLServer data?
And how do I save them?

Comment: Yes, my boss forces me to use it ahahaha  @SurajKumar

Comment: The error is because the combo is inside the UserControl.  You can add properties and methods to your UserControl to do whatever you require.  So in this case, I would create a method called `LoadCombo` (you can give it a more meaningful name) passing in a RecordSet.

Comment: thanks, i ve a dude when I press the add button it takes too long to copy the data into the picturebox, do you know why? 
I have added the complete code of the modified UserControl @BrianMStafford

Comment: I would guess it has to do with the database logic since that was the only change you made.  With this code, every control will have an open connection to the database and query for data.  It would be better to move the query back to the main form and just pass in a recordset for every control you create.  Query once, and pass it  multiple times in other words.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load a combo inside a UserControl and later save the selection, I would add additional methods and properties to the UserControl:

```
Public Sub LoadAddType(ByVal Data As ADODB.Recordset)
   cmbAddType.Clear
   Data.MoveFirst

   Do While Not Data.EOF
       cmbAddType.AddItem Data!tipo
       cmbAddType.ItemData(cmbAddType.NewIndex) = Data!idTipo
       Data.MoveNext
   Loop
End Sub

Public Sub LoadAddType2()
   ***or this could be in UserControl_Initialize()
   cmbAddType.Clear
   cmbAddType.AddItem "celular"
   cmbAddType.AddItem "option2"
End Sub

Public Property Get AddTypeID() As Integer
   AddTypeID = cmbAddType.ItemData(cmbAddType.ListIndex)
End Property
```

Keeping all the database connection and querying on the main form, you could then initialize your UserControls like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    uc1(0).LoadAddType rs
End Sub
```

And every time you add a UserControl:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
    uc1(indice).LoadAddType rs
End Sub
```

To save user selections, the general idea would be:

```
Private Sub btnGuardar_Click()
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim id As Integer
   Dim sel As String

   Dim CM As ADODB.Command

   For i = 0 To indice
      id = uc1(i).AddTypeID
      sel = uc1(i).AddType

      ***with the retrieved data, build your CM object
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: where is the select to load combo data? or how to load combo data without a select?

Comment: If I add `.Open" SELECT typeType, type FROM number_type ", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic` I get the following error:
`the connection cannot be used to perform the operation-it is either closed or invalid`

Comment: The connection and select logic is on the main form, just like you had it originally.  If you don't have a RecordSet, then the LoadAddType method may not have a parameter and have hard-coded AddItem calls.  Or you can have any combination of these techniques.  It's up to you as the designer how you want to set this up.

Comment: But, when i press add button this don't copy information down.

Comment: This post was only answering the question you asked.  It is meant as a guide in adding these features to your app.  To copy information down, refer to my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59666324/5162073) where I showed how to do this.

Comment: Yes, it was my fault with the method.Thank you so much for your answer