# Copy objects with a button vb6

Tags: button, combobox, vb6

Project structure and `UserControl`:

[image]

```
Formularios = Form = Form1
Controles de Usuario = User Controls = uc1
```

All `UserControl` Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Get AddType() As String
   AddType = cmbAddExample.Text
End Property

Public Property Let AddType(ByVal Value As String)
   cmbAddExample.Text = Value
End Property

Public Property Get AddNumber() As String
   AddNumber = Text1.Text
End Property

Public Property Let AddNumber(ByVal Value As String)
   Text1.Text = Value
End Property
```

[image]

`Button` Add(Añadir) Code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim indice As Integer

Private Sub btnAñadir_Click()
   indice = indice + 1

   Load uc1(indice)
   Set uc1(indice).Container = Picture1 
   uc1(indice).Visible = True
   uc1(indice).Top = IIf(indice = 1, 0, uc1(indice - 1).Top + uc1(indice - 1).Height + 20)

   Load cmbAddExample(indice)
   Set cmbAddExample(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   cmbAddExample(indice).Visible = True
   cmbAddExample(indice).Top = cmbAddExample(indice - 1).Top
   CargaIDTipoNumero

   Load Text1(indice)
   Set Text1(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   Text1(indice).Visible = True
   Text1(indice).Top = Text1(indice - 1).Top

   uc1(indice).AddType = uc1(0).AddType
   uc1(indice).AddType = ""

   Picture1.Visible = True

   If indice = 3 Then
   Me.btnAñadir.Enabled = False
   End If
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Black Circle is a `UserControl` with a `TextBox` and a `ComboBox` inside. Red Circle is a `PictureBox`.

So, the problem is that i need copy values from uc1 in `PictureBox` when i press the button add. But when i press the button, it shows me the next error:

[image]

[image]

```
Compilation Error: Method or data member not found.
```

In this line:

[image]

```
uc1(index).AddType = uc1(0).AddType
```

So, any sugerence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your post, you say the object circled in black is a UserControl when in fact it is a PictureBox named `uc1(0)`.  Since a PictureBox does not have an AddType property, you receive the error.

Replacing this PictureBox with a UserControl will resolve the error.

Comment: Ehm, no. The object in black circle is a UserControl

Comment: Not according to the animated graphic.  When you click on the object in the black circle, it shows in the Property window as a PictureBox.

Comment: i've a simple question, how to add usercontrol in components? 'cause i can't see

Comment: Make sure the UserControl is not open in the editor.  Now in the Tool palette, you should see a control with 4 little buttons and a pencil.  Click on this control to add it to your form.

Comment: Thank's but new error is here: `Object doesn't support this property or method` in line `Load uc1(indice)`

Comment: Don't forget to set the `Index` of the UserControl to `0`.

Comment: So, to load the data from the sql server into the combobox, do I have to do it inside the UserControl?

Comment: No, you use the Properties you added to the UserControl.  Again, I suggest you review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59413007/5162073) which covers this in more detail.

Comment: Can I contact you by any means other than this to clarify some doubts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206005/discussion-between-franqo-balsamo-and-brian-m-stafford).